# How to center fillPatternImage inside wedge?

Tags: javascript, canvas, kineticjs

I have several wedges spinning around an axis, forming a circle. I'm using fillPatternImage to set a background for each wedge. Each image is a blank image with text in the center. All images have the same with and are wider than the wedges.

What I'd I'm trying to do is set the fillPatternImage in the center of the wedge. The problem is, the wedge doesn't seem to have a width or height attribute. I use radius and degrees to place them around the axis.

I'm aware I could use fillPatternImageOffset to offset the backgrounds to **((background width - wedge width) / 2)**, instead of 0,0 of the wedge. But as I mentioned before, I have no width nor height for the wedge.

**Visual explanation:**
[image]

Might someone have an idea of how I could center the fillPatternImage inside the wedge so it seems the wedge has the text centered?

Thanks in advance for your help and time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can use trigonometry to calculate the width/height of the triangle portion of the wedge:**

In this illustration, the red line is width and the yellow line is height.

[image]

```
function calcWedgeDimensions(x,y,radius,angleDeg){
    var angleRad=angleDeg*Math.PI/180;
    var r=-(angleRad/2+Math.PI/2);
    var x1=x+radius*Math.cos(-angleRad/2-Math.PI/2);
    var y1=y+radius*Math.sin(r);
    var x2=x+radius*Math.cos(+angleRad/2-Math.PI/2);
    return({width:x2-x1,height:y-y1});
}
```

If needed, you can use context.measureText to get the width of your text to center it:

```
  function calcTextWidth(text,font){
      context.font = font;
      var metrics = context.measureText(text);
      return(metrics.width);
  }
```

Comment: That worked perfectly markE. Thanks. All I need now for perfect text is the correct rotation degree. All text elements have different lengths, so they all should have a different rotation degree. Any ideas?